# Sessions are making me pull my hair out

Tags: php, session

login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];


$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'smithrwg_database');

$_SESSION['username'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['username']);

$query = "SELECT id, password, salt, priv FROM tbl_mem WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header('Location: index1.php');
    exit;
    session_destroy();
}



$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $pass) );

if($hash != $userData['password']) // Incorrect password. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header('Location: oeifnweoifn.php');

}else {
// Redirect to home page after successful login.


    header('Location: dashboard.php');
        $_SESSION['username'] = $userData['username'];
    $_SESSION['priv'] = $userData['priv'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userData['id'];



}
?>
```

at the moment every one of the $_SESSION's work but $_SESSION['username'] wont echo and aparantly contains nothing although the rest of the session information still works.

Comment: Oh dear ... Why do you try to build your own login system when you have absolutly no idea what you are doing ? This code will bring you into lots of problems.

Comment: it's called trying to learn, sorry for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because of *_SESSION* it's because of your query that you did not select **username**.
Change

```
$query = "SELECT id, password, salt, priv FROM tbl_mem WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
```

To

```
$query = "SELECT id, username, password, salt, priv FROM tbl_mem WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
```

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. I've had help from everyone in this room who are much better than me at this, i've asked everyone if this needed to be added and was told like 5 times from each person no.

works tho, thanks!

Comment: @user3013008 Why did you mark this as the correct answer when it is what I told you was wrong? You were referencing `$userData['user']` when you were not populating a `user` element in the `$userData` array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT password, salt, priv FROM tbl_mem WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['user']}'";

$_SESSION['user'] = $userData['user'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $userData['id'];
```

You're not selecting `user` or `id` in your query

For the record, you really shouldn't be storing the user's password in the session. Sessions are often vulnerable to attack, so this is bad practice.

Comment: Storing a password hash in a session? This doesn't sound like a best pratice, op should be aware.

Comment: @Fabio Yes, storing the password in session is generally bad practice. That doesn't answer the OP's question though.

Comment: No it doesn't but to have a good answer you should let him know, by the way, he's also storing username and password in session before actual checking if user exists

Comment: just fixed that thanks. Narrowed it down to just user not working.

Comment: edited my code to what im at now. really no idea what i've done wrong.